# Powershell tee command locks file

Tags: windows, powershell

Is it possible to run powershell `tee` command so that it doesn't lock the file, allowing to view it?

Comment: please share a code sample, also, what do you mean by 'view it'? are you appending to an existing file?

Comment: Tee enables you to see the output on screen too. Isn't that sufficient? After the command's done you can take a look at the log.

Comment: @Karan What if the command works too long and the output is too big to follow?

Comment: I suppose that could be an issue. Hopefully someone will be able to come up with a solution for you.

Comment: Probably the easiest solution would be to switch from ps's tee.